# Twitter Bootstrap Modal - On hidden any

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on Bootstrap to put a video in a modal. Everything is generated via cms (so I dont have control on how much videos will be shown.)

Everything is going fine (I have to give each modal its own ID and everything works). Thing is, when you close the modal and the video is running, the video (and sound) continue to run in the background.

To dodge that, when a modal is closing with the x button, I refresh the html in the modal, like this:

```
$('button.close').click(function(){
    var divcible=$(this).parent().parent().find(".modal-body");
    var html = divcible.html()
    divcible.html("")
    divcible.html(html)
})
```

My problem with that is that if the user clicks the backdrop, the Html won't reset. on the website of boostrap they call this

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

to monitor when one modal closes, but I want to find if there's a way to monitor when ANY modal closes.

Comment: Have you tried `$('.modal-body').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})`? Base your selector on a class name rather than by ID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a class to your modals and use that:

```
$('.myModal').on('hidden', function () {
   // do something…

   // edit for clarity: "that" will now reference the modal that was hidden
   var that = this;          
})
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

from bootstrap 3.x documentation
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Thanks. I was using Bootstrap v4 alpha and I needed "hidden.bs.modal" for it to work, just like you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, most events [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) from the original event target to the `document` element. This is also the case of the `hidden` event which is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user. Thus, a way to monitor when ANY modal closes is to attach an event handler to the `document` element as follows:

```
$(document).on('hidden', function () {
  // a modal closes, so do what you want :)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're not checking if you're actually handling a modal here, are you?

Comment: In fact, the Twitter Bootstrap modal component trigger an event called 'hidden'. There is no namespace, no additional information about the origin of this event. Anytime you catch an event named 'hidden' you have to be sure that there is no other component which can trigger the same event with the same name. The problem is exactly the same even if you consider the @Terry's solution. This is not a matter of where you catch the event but what event is triggered and with which name.

Comment: Okay. Although, to be fair, Terry's solution makes sure that only the correct modals are considered. It's a bit more work, though.

Comment: I'm absolutely OK with the @Terry's solution, but in order to be exhaustive I had to propose the other alternative. It's far more sure to know the correct modal.

Comment: The problem with using the global document is that the value of `this` becomes the `document`.  If you do a `console.log(this);` inside the callback you will see why using the class selector is preferred.